# Filter dataframe by colum values from other 2 dataframes

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I've got these 2 dataframes (**dats** and **datxt**):

```
> head(dats)
  idpatient entryear  sex   infection
1         1     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-
2         2     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-
3         3     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-
4         4     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-
5         5     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-
6         6     1995 Male HCV+ & HIV-

> head(datxt)
  idpatient entryear    sex   infection timeaddic
1        54     1996 Female HCV+ & HIV-       168
2        55     1996 Female HCV+ & HIV-        96
3        56     1996 Female HCV+ & HIV-       108
4        57     1996 Female HCV+ & HIV-        60
5        58     1996 Female HCV+ & HIV-        96
6        59     1996   Male HCV+ & HIV-        24
```

On the other side, I merged these two into other one (**mergedDataset**):

```
> tail(**mergedDataset**)
    idpatient entryear    sex   infection timeaddic
358       358     2004   Male HCV+ & HIV+       180
359       359     2004   Male HCV+ & HIV+       288
360       360     2004 Female HCV+ & HIV+       192
361       361     2004   Male HCV+ & HIV-        60
362       362     2004   Male HCV+ & HIV-       108
363       363     2004   Male HCV+ & HIV+       252
```

How can I extract the data in megedDataset from the patients included in dats and and datxt? I tried this but doesnt work:

```
finalData <- mergedData[dats$idpatient == datxt$idpatient,]
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `merge()`to merge the dataset, the new dataset consists, depending on the arguments, only on
 objects (determined by an unique id) which are in both datasets.

```
df1<-data.frame(id= 1:5, x = rnorm(5))
df2<-data.frame(id=c(1:3,5:6),y=rnorm(5))

>merge(df1,df2)

  id          x          y
1  1  0.3623482 -0.1592616
2  2 -0.8280637 -0.9261413
3  3  1.0900202  0.2681832
4  5  0.7551957 -0.1201221

df<-merge(df1,df2, all = TRUE)
>df
 id          x          y
1  1  0.3623482 -0.1592616
2  2 -0.8280637 -0.9261413
3  3  1.0900202  0.2681832
4  4 -0.0620777         NA
5  5  0.7551957 -0.1201221
6  6         NA  0.8578393
```

That is closest to your approach:

```
ids<-df1$id[df1$id %in% df2$id]
>df[df$id %in% ids, ]

  id          x          y
1  1  0.3623482 -0.1592616
2  2 -0.8280637 -0.9261413
3  3  1.0900202  0.2681832
4  5  0.7551957 -0.1201221
```

What you tried returns:

```
filter<-match(df1$id,df2$id)
>na.omit(df[filter,])

   id          x          y
1  1  0.3623482 -0.1592616
2  2 -0.8280637 -0.9261413
3  3  1.0900202  0.2681832
```

That does not seem right.